# Maven multi modules dependencies

Tags: maven

I want to create multi module in Maven.

The structure looks like this:

```
parent  
       ->  application (spring boot app)
       ->  acceptance-test
```

In the acceptance-test module I want to have access to classes from applications necessary for testing. The problem is that during the compilation acceptance-test module I am getting the error that classes are not found. Intellij doesn't indicate some problem.

parent pom.xml

```
    <modules>
        <module>application</module>
        <module>acceptance-test</module>
    </modules>
```

The acceptance-test module use maven-shade-plugin to build jar as executable jar

Answer (score 0):

You can add the `application` module as dependency in the `acceptance-test` module.

Basically

For a project structure as:

```
Parent Project: sampleproject
   |-- child A: Module1
   |-- child A: Module1
   |-- child B: UtilMethods
```

Here UtilMethods has classes to be used in both Module1 and Module2.

This is how pom.xml of Parent Project looks like:

```
<groupId>com.parent</groupId>
<artifactId>sampleproject</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0</version>
.
.
<modules>
  <module>Module1</module>
  <module>Module2</module>
  <module>UtilMethods</module>
</modules>
```

And the pom for Modules will look like this:

UtilMethods:

```
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.parent</groupId>
        <artifactId>sampleproject</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </parent>
    <artifactId>UtilMethods</artifactId>
```

Module1:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>com.parent</groupId>
    <artifactId>sampleproject</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
</parent>
<artifactId>Module1</artifactId>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.parent</groupId>
        <artifactId>UtilMethods</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Module2

```
<parent>
    <groupId>com.parent</groupId>
    <artifactId>sampleproject</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
</parent>
<artifactId>Module2</artifactId>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.parent</groupId>
        <artifactId>UtilMethods</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Answer (score 0):

`Spring Boot` produce a `jar` with custom content.

Application classes and dependencies are placed in special custom location in `Spring Boot` jar.

So you can not use `Spring Boot Application` as dependency for another modules, classes will not found in such jar.

You can create next standard jar module with shared classes which you can use in `Spring Boot Application` and in other like mentioned acceptance-test